# Fact sales is showing null in cube whereas sales showing up in fact table

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas, bids

SSAS Cube is not showing sales for 2014, I researched that is used in cube and it is showing the sales for 2014.

Here is my query which shows below sales for Dec and Jan in data warehouse

```
SELECT SUM(InvoiceExtPrice)AS InvoiceSales FROM  [DM_Corp].[FactInvoiceSales]
WHERE InvoiceDateKey BETWEEN '20131201' AND '20131231'  -- 13676760.4507

SELECT SUM(InvoiceExtPrice)AS InvoiceSales FROM  [DM_Corp].[FactInvoiceSales]
WHERE InvoiceDateKey BETWEEN '20140101' AND '20140107' --511078.9933
```

Here is what cube showing for Dec 2013 and Jan 2014. Dec matched but Jan is not showing at all

```
Invoice Year    Invoice month    Invoicesales
Calender 2013   December 2013    $12,675,860.45
```

`FactInvoiceSales` is measure and `invoicedatekey` is dimension

Could not able to find reason why it is not showing 2014, how can I see the data in cube?

I checked all dimensions involved in dates, it contains data for 2014.

Answer (score 0):

I  figured why cube is not showing data for 2014, It is due to Partitions Cube has existing partitions till 2013

Have to create a new partition for 2014 fixed the issue!